# Celery task executed always but only returning if condition is met?

Tags: python, celery

I'm working with Python 3 and Celery (v5.3.6).
I have a workflow that looks something like...

`part1_task`
`part2_task`

Both Part1 and Part2 hit different external APIs, and the time they take to finish is variable: most of times Part1 finishes first (ideal scenario) and its results are presented before Part2's.

Right now we use a `group` to run both in parallel, as we need to process things ASAP.

But some times Part B finishes first... and we cannot show its results as Part1's must be presented first.

How can I make it so...

- If Part1 is ready first, return it ASAP (and then Part2 will come along)
- If Part2 is ready first, wait for Part1's completion and return both results at the same time

The goal is to show parts in correct order and ASAP so users see progress.
Thanks!

Our current approach is to make the `group` wait for both parts to be completed, and then reveal them one after the other